# How to query MySQL as a list of column name and value instead of table

Tags: mysql

If i'm not forgotten, in PostgreSQL I could display query result as a list, for example:

```
   id : 123
 name : 'test'
 foo  : 'bar'
```

instead of standard result:

```
+----+------+-----+
| id | name | foo |
+----+------+-----+
| 123|test  |bar  |
+----+------+-----+
```

How to do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mysql command line you can do as

```
select * from tablename \G
```